# PHP regex - match everything but not exactly one or more word

Tags: php, regex

I try to find any string it not exactly one or more word

My pattern

```
(?!(^ignoreme$)|(^ignoreme2$))
```

Iam looking for

```
ignoreme   - no
ignoreme2  - no
ignoremex  - match
ignorem    - match
gnoreme    - match
ignoreme22 - match
```

But it return many space. How to do that thank.
https://regex101.com/r/u4EsNv/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this corrected regex:

```
^(?!ignoreme2?$).*$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u4EsNv/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!ignoreme2?$)`: Negartive lookahead to fail the match when we have `ignoreme` or `ignoreme2` ahead till end.
- `.*`: Match 0 more of any characters
- `$`: End

---

Note that regex `(?!(^ignoreme$)|(^ignoreme2$))` matches first 2 invalid cases because you have included `^` in negative lookahead expressions not outside. This causes regex engine to start matching after 1st character to satisfy lookahead assertions. (You can see that in regex101 highlighted matches)

Comment: it look cool, but it not separation, b/c i can add many word like `ignoreme2, ignoreme, top, abc`

Comment: Sure you can add them with alternation e.g. `^(?!(ignoreme2?|top|abc|foo|bar)$).*$`